# Using a Variable as a Property in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

A bit of a PowerShell neophyte here, so please be kind. I am creating a PS script which is helping me to document my environment. What I am trying to do is get the names of all of an object's properties and populate an XML document with the property names and corresponding values. For example:

```
PS C:\> $stuff = Get-SomeStuff
PS C:\> $stuff
Name: foo
Version: 1.0
```

The output XML would look like this:

```
<rootNode>
    <stuff>
        <Name>foo</Name>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
    </stuff>
</rootNode>
```

Essentially I want to use the $stuff property names to substitute for the properties when retrieving the object properties. Essentially I need to dynamically substitute the property name with the extracted name. My code looks like this:

```
$stuff = Get-SomeStuff
CreateXML $rootnode,"stuff",$stuff

Function CreateXML ($rootNode, $nodeName, $category){
    $subRootNode = $xml.CreateElement($nodeName)
    $catProps = $stuff | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    foreach ($prop in $catProps){
        $newNode = $xml.CreateElement($prop)
        $newNode.Text = $category.{$prop} #--- THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING PROBLEMS
        $subRootNode.AppendChild($newNode)
    }
$rootNode.AppendChild($subRootNode)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as there are thousands of properties I have to capture across multiple nodes.

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it, but where does $category come from?

Comment: What is `Get-SomeStuff`? And what problems exactly does `$category.{$prop}` cause?

Comment: Actually, it's easier than you're trying.  $category.$prop should work.

Comment: Get-SomeStuff was just a dummy cmdlet to simplify the explanation. In terms of the problem it causes, it doesn't work. I was able to establish that the output of doing it that way would dump property typing, not the property itself.

Comment: Mike, I tried that originally but nothing gets sent through the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
[xml]$xml = '<rootNode></rootNode>'    

$stuff | foreach {

    $node = $xml.CreateElement('stuff')

    $_.psobject.properties | foreach{
        $prop = $xml.CreateElement($_.Name)
        $prop.InnerText = $_.value
        $node.AppendChild($prop)
    }

    $xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($node)   

}

$xml
```